# IE11 issue : xhr.send() is throwing invalid parameter

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

I am using FILE API with javascript to upload files.

The utility is working fine in Chrome and mozilla, but in IE am getting the below exception:

SCRIPT87: The parameter is incorrect.
Please find the code sample am using below:

```
var control = document.getElementById('rsFile');
var file= control.files[0];
request.open(method, url);
request.send(file);
```

Comment: Do you know if IE supports that API in the same way as the other two browsers?

Comment: Yes, File API is supported in IE 10+